# How to upgrade SAMBA to latest version?

Tags: upgrade, samba

My Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS 64 bit. My Samba version is 4.1.6. Latest Samba version is 4.1.13. How can I upgrade to this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the latest version of Samba available on Ubuntu is [4.1.11 for 14.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/samba), and the [Samba team's PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~samba-team) are long dead, it looks like the only way you can upgrade to 4.1.13 is installing from source.

Comment: would you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @FarshadForoughi the samba docs have a chapter on this: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/compiling.html try it out and update the question if you have a problem.

Comment: For version 4, https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_Source or [this AskUbuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/813177/100072)