# Latest Upstream Samba on Ubuntu 16.04 how?

Tags: smb

I offered to test for a bug report I filed concerning Samba on Ubuntu 16.04 and the bug owner has asked me to install the latest upstream version of Samba to compare.

Can anyone help me locate instructions for doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update 2024-02-21:

In order to install the latest upstream version of Samba, you will first need to install Samba's dependencies. According to [this article](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Operating_system_requirements/Dependencies_-_Libraries_and_programs), the following should install what you need

```
 sudo apt-get install acl attr autoconf bison build-essential \
 debhelper dnsutils docbook-xml docbook-xsl flex gdb krb5-user \
 libacl1-dev libaio-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libbsd-dev \
 libcap-dev libcups2-dev libgnutls28-dev libjson-perl \
 libldap2-dev libncurses5-dev libpam0g-dev libparse-yapp-perl \
 libpopt-dev libreadline-dev perl perl-modules pkg-config \
 python-all-dev xsltproc zlib1g-dev libgpgme11-dev \
 liblmdb-dev libjansson-dev libarchive-dev
```

You can then download the the latest version of samba [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/ftp/samba-latest.tar.gz).

Once you extract the archive to a directory, you can run the following in the directory to which you have extracted:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

For further instructions on building samba, see [this article](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Build_Samba_from_source).

Comment: Up-stream bug filed:  https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12160